# how to wait for webclient OpenReadAsync to complete

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, async-await, task-parallel-library, webclient

I am using WebClient to download some stuff from internet in Windows Phone 8.1 app.
Below is the sample code i am using in my app - where i am calling below method, but my webclient is not waiting to complete the read operation and returning immediately after OpenReadAsync call.

how can i make sure that my method return operation must wait till OpenReadCompleted event is completed?
I have seen multiple similar questions, but couldn't find a solution.

```
MyCustomObject externalObj;  // my custom object

private static void CheckNetworkFile()
{
    try
    {
        WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
        webClient.OpenReadCompleted += (s, e) =>
        {
          externalObj = myReadWebclientResponse(e.Result); // my custom method to read the response
        };

        webClient.OpenReadAsync(new Uri("http://externalURl.com/sample.xml", UriKind.Absolute));                
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
      externalObj = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Make the method `async`. If you don't know what that means, go read about `async` methods in C#

Comment: Thanks @Alxandr for the reply, i did tried using async/await but same behavior. OpenReadCompleted event completes after the method return call.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I would advise you to use [`WebClient.OpenReadTaskAsync`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh159420(v=vs.110).aspx) with a combination of the [`async/await`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx) keywords introduced in .NET 4.5 instead. You need to add the `async` keyword to your method, make it return a `Task` and it is advisable to end your method with the `Async` postfix:

```
MyCustomObject externalObj;

private static async Task CheckNetworkFileAsync()
{
    try
    {
        WebClient webClient = new WebClient();

        Stream stream = await webClient.OpenReadTaskAsync(new Uri("http://externalURl.com/sample.xml", UriKind.Absolute));                
        externalObj = myReadWebclientResponse(stream);
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
      externalObj = null;
    }
}
```

**Edit:**

As you said, `WebClient.OpenReadTaskAsync` isn't available for WP8.1, So lets create an Extension Method so it will be:

```
public static class WebClientExtensions 
{
    public static Task<Stream> OpenReadTaskAsync(this WebClient client, Uri uri)
    {
       var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<Stream>();

       OpenReadCompletedEventHandler openReadEventHandler = null;
       openReadEventHandler = (sender, args) => 
       {
          try 
          {
             tcs.SetResult(args.Result);
          } 
          catch (Exception e)
          {
             tcs.SetException(e);
          }
       };

       client.OpenReadCompleted += openReadEventHandler;
       client.OpenReadAsync(uri);

       return tcs.Task;
    }
}
```

Now you can use it on your `WebClient`.

You can find great reading material in the [*async-await wiki*](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/async-await/info) and by simply filtering by that tag in the search bar.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, actually this OpenReadTaskAsync() is not in the WindowsPhone platform.

Comment: Salam,
I think you must change "taskComplete" to "tcs.SetResult(...)"

Comment: Thanks for the extension hint.

Comment: OH MY GOD!!! This is the single most important code example for Silverlight I have ever seen. This not only works for REST calls, it also works for WCF calls. Up until now, I have been using the old async model without the async/await operators to call WCF/REST methods. Our code is littered with horrible event handlers everywhere and the code is like a maze to navigate. This will clean up our code immensely. I should mention though, that in order to use this, we must add the Microsoft.Bcl.Async NuGet package. That was the other key to unlocking this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is not too off topic, but others who are researching this might like to know that the above code sample can also be used for WCF calls in Silverlight. Be sure to add the Microsoft.Bcl.Async NuGet package first. Here is a WCF code example:

```
  public static async Task<string> AuthenticateAsync(string userName, string password)
    {
        var dataAccessServiceClient = new DataAccessServiceClient("DataAccessService");

        var taskCompletionSource = new TaskCompletionSource<string>();

        EventHandler<AuthenticateCompletedEventArgs> completedHandler = null;
        completedHandler = (s, args) =>
        {
            try
            {
                taskCompletionSource.SetResult(args.Result);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                taskCompletionSource.SetException(e);
            }
        };

        dataAccessServiceClient.AuthenticateCompleted += completedHandler;
        dataAccessServiceClient.AuthenticateAsync(userName, password);

        return await taskCompletionSource.Task;
    }
```

It can be called like this:

```
var result = await AuthenticateAsync(username, password);
```